# how to mimic date array for singledate -react date picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

i have 2 different react date picker 1 for single date 1 for date range depending on different page

i want to receive  [newDate, newDate] for both cases how do i do that

here is my implementation

```
  <DatePicker 
                
        selected={Array.isArray(value)?value[0]:value}

              isSingleDate
                      onChange={(v) => {
                        console.log(name,value)
                        handleChange({ target: { name, value: v } });
                      }}
                    />
                     
                  ) : (
            
                <DatePicker 
                    startDate={value[0]}
                    endDate={value[1]}
             
                    selectsRange
                

                    onChange={(v) => {
console.log(name,value)
                    handleChange({ target: { name, value: v } });
                    }}
                />
```